# Stop timers on user scroll

Tags: javascript, timer, event-handling, dom-events

I have a `div` tag that fills with data when an Ajax call is made to my server.
The Ajax `request` is fired every `10` seconds from within a `timer` with `setInterval`.
This div has a scroll bar.

I would like to disable Ajax within timer whenever user scrolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
var t = setInterval(function(){ 
            /*ajax call here*/ 
        }, 10000);

divId.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    clearInterval(t);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **clearInterval** function to clear the setInterval action once user scrolls. This function will basically clears a timer set with the setInterval() method.

```
var sInterval = setInterval(function xyz () {}, 10*1000);

//And in the scroll event just clear the interval,
clearInterval(sInterval);
```